# initialize bootstrap dropdown after appended with jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have on my webpage a block/section with inputs and dropdowns (bootstrap), and would like to be able to clone and append the first block/section and put the cloned block/section under the "original" block/section. But when doing that, the bootstrap dropdown stops to work. The jquery never alters the `<select>` into a "styled" version..

Any ideas?

[image]

As you can see, when you click the blue button, everything above it will be clonded and appended directly above the blue button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions!

What i did was, i first destoryed the dropdown like this:

```
$(".select-simple").select2("destroy");
```

After i have appended the clone, i reinitilizes it like this:

```
$('.select-simple').select2({minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity});
```

Super easy!

Comment: That's not a bootstrap dropdown